# Share printer with Google API Service Account

Tags: google-cloud-print

Is it possible to share a GCP printer with a Google API service account (https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2ServiceAccount)?

I tried to share the printer with the client email address (*id@developer.gserviceaccount.com*), but the printer is not shown in the response to the API call `/search`.
Calling `/submit` leads to an error (*User has no access*)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I believe you are encountering the "***is pending***" problem.
Namely, you did share your printer with the *id@developer.gserviceaccount.com* account but the other user (in this case *id@developer.gserviceaccount.com*) has to accept the invitation to share the printer.

You can check this by issuing the `/print` request and you will see an

> "is_pending": true

element in the `access` section for your user (*id@developer.gserviceaccount.com*) in this case.

Needless to say that accounts that have this element set to true cannot print - hence the "User is not authorized." message.
I know no way to accept the invitation for the given service account however there is a workaround:

1. You can create a private google group with an account that can accept shared printers (e.g. your gmail account).
2. Then you add the service account ("id@developer.gserviceaccount.com") to the group et voila. You can print with the service account ;).

When you share the printer you must share it with the google group (use the group's email address which you can find somewhere in the group management console) and the group manager (e.g. your gmail account) must accept the invitation for the whole group.

More info on how to create the group can be found [here](https://support.google.com/chromebook/answer/1241064).
I have tried this with a GAE service account and it works. If you need any clarification do not hesitate to ask. Good luck.

Comment: You're an absolute genius.

Answer (score 25):

As you yourself shared the printer with the service account, we can assume you know the "Printer ID" of the printer to which the service account has been invited.

Have the service account call the `/processinvite` request, with these (mandatory) parameters:

- `printerid` = *the-known-printer-id*
- `accept` = `true`

After that, the printer will appear in `/search`

Happy printing!

Comment: This works and your answer is the only place on the web this is "documented".

Comment: Can confirm--this works perfectly! 
1) From the Cloud Print dashboard, share the printer with the service account.
2) Have the service account POST `/processinvite` -- the easiest way to get the printer ID is to copy it from the URL of the dashboard page (`https://www.google.com/cloudprint#printers/<printer-id>`)

Comment: I added this command to a library with example code for the process at https://github.com/io7/GoogleCloudPrint

Comment: Thank you. I can't even begin to imagine how you found this undocumented trick.

Comment: i was going to rip my hair out until i found this answer. 3 days of pain. oh my god!

Comment: I can't test this, I've shared a printer through API (/share) with a test user to service account and then /processinvite with the service account returns success, but the printers does not apperar nor /search or /printer.